# How do I get Ctrl-Backspace to delete a word in vim within gnome-terminal?

Tags: linux, vim, ascii, gnome-terminal

I'd like Ctrl-Backspace to delete the current word in vim insert mode.  From within xterm I can pull this off via

```
:inoremap <C-H> <C-W>
```

but in gnome-terminal I cannot figure out a way to make it happen.

When in vim insert mode, if I type control-v and then press backspace, I get ^H in xterm, and ^? in gnome-terminal.  Unfortunately,

```
:inoremap <C-?> <C-W>
```

doesn't do the trick in gnome-terminal; control-backspace just erases a single character no matter what.

**Regarding ASCII codes:**

Gnome-terminal lets you change the backspace character under Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Compatibility.  Unfortunately, no option works, as far as I can tell: whatever character I apply to Backspace via the settings, if I try mapping the character itself, like

```
:inoremap <C-H> <C-W>
```

then regular backspace and control-backspace both erase an entire word; and if I try mapping control plus that character, like

```
:inoremap <C-^H> <C-W>
```

then regular backspace and control-backspace just erase a single character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

gnome-terminal's libvte would need to be patched.

libvte already has several options to map backspace, none of which distinguish Ctrl-backspace. It needs an option that does, maybe one that follows the behaviour of the linux console (^? for backspace, ^H for Ctrl-backspace). See [this gnome bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420039).

---

2015 update: this was fixed in [23c7cd0f99d504cbab06d4c27254d4f3e2807ba8](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/commit/?id=23c7cd0f99d504cbab06d4c27254d4f3e2807ba8).

libvte 0.41.90, 0.40.3 and newer have the fix.

Comment: How can we get this patch working? What steps would I need to take (to recompile libvte and gnome-terminal)?

Comment: @StevenLu Forward-port the patch, expose the configuration to gnome-term (you could edit the gconf/dconf directly from gconf-editor though), make sure your recompiled libvte is in the load path.

Comment: Looks like this patch got some attention last month and might be released soon. Can't wait. I need ctrl-backspace in console vim for sanity.