# In zsh how do you bind Ctrl+backspace to delete the previous word?

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to bind the command usualy binded to ^W with ctrl+backspace.

I have two problem here, one for each parameter of the bindkey command:

- what is string to mean the ctrl+backspace
- what is the command to delete the previous word

Comment: While some control key combinations have straightforward ASCII equivalents (Control-H sending ASCII 0x08, for example), control-backspace does not. Your terminal emulator must be configured to generate a string, much like it does for a function key or arrow key.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One may use `bindkey '^H' backward-kill-word`.

Note that, on old versions of GNOME terminal, it won't work; see [How do I get Ctrl-Backspace to delete a word in vim within gnome-terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715537/how-do-i-get-ctrl-backspace-to-delete-a-word-in-vim-within-gnome-terminal) and [Bug 420039 - VTE doesn't distinguish between backspace and control-backspace](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420039).
As reported by thorbjornwolf in his comment, [commit 23c7cd0f](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/commit/23c7cd0f99d504cbab06d4c27254d4f3e2807ba8) fixed it.

Comment: The related question's accepted answer was updated on 2015-11-09: [The   gnome terminal problem seems to be fixed.](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/commit/?id=23c7cd0f99d504cbab06d4c27254d4f3e2807ba8)

Comment: Then whats the keybinding for ctrl+H ?

Comment: how to specify to `delete everything` (what i typed before hitting `enter`)?

Comment: Try `^U` for everything before the cursor on the current line, `^K` for what comes after.

Answer (score 7):

As I pointed out [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698884/522013) there is a chance that the keystrokes are different in some systems.

If the output of `showkey -a` is:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is `^?`

then you should add the following line in your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
bindkey '^?' backward-kill-word
```

Comment: `showkey -a` is extremely useful!